# Trouble by running boilerpipe library in python

Tags: java, python, jvm, boilerpipe, jpype

I'have tried to use boilerpipe library on python aiming to extract text from pages for a college project.
 I created a simple code to make the extraction that is:

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
def Article(url):
    extractor = Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', url=your_url)
    extracted_text = extractor.getText()
    return extracted_text
```

and the error i'm getting when I try to run is this:

```
>Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\Python27\Boiler.py", line 1, in <module>
>    from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boilerpipe-1.2.0-py2.7.egg\boilerpipe\__init__.py", >line 10, in <module>
>    jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-Djava.class.path=%s" % >os.pathsep.join(jars))
>  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 44, in startJVM
>    _jpype.startup(jvm, tuple(args), True)
>RuntimeError: Unable to load DLL [C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll], error = >Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
> at src/native/common/include\jp_platform_win32.h:58
```

I have already checked for JVM and JRE and they are correctly installed and the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable setted.

anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What happens if you follow the installation as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28947982/179014 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPype won't compile properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029760/jpype-wont-compile-properly)